# remove large white spacing at the end of webpage

Tags: html, css

the webpage has a lot of white space at the end of the web page. I have no margins, padding or height restrictions.

All of the webpage content is contained in a div called full:

```
#full{ background-color:#181818; height:1380px; min-width:1061px; text-align:center}
#full{ background-color:#181818; height:1380px; min-width:1061px; text-align:center}
#full{ background-color:#181818; height:1380px; min-width:1061px; text-align:center}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover your contact us navigation option the answer will become very clear.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a number of HTML issues in your website; HTML Validator is showing me 72 errors (mostly closing tags and improper structure) - fix those first and see what you have. I recommend the [HTML Validator addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/) to get you started.

Biggest issue I saw is that you're missing the opening `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Exact lines that cause your "whitespace problem" are 228-232

```
<h2><a href="http://www.facebook.com/ubreakirepair"><img src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/facebookmenu.png" id="cufacebook"></a></h2>
```

and such. Remove them and that whitespace is gone. But there's a lot more problems in your HTML than that. I recommend usind a validator.